# Undefined property: MySQLDatabase::$db_config

Tags: php

I have no idea why I am getting this error and i've been struggling on how to fix it for 5 hours please help.
Undefined property: MySQLDatabase::$db_config

```
class MySQLDatabase {
  function __construct(){
if(file_exists(ROOT_PATH.'config.php')){
        $db_config = json_decode(file_get_contents(ROOT_PATH.'config.php'), true);
        $this->open_connection(db_config);
}}

function open_connection() {
    $this->connection = mysqli_connect(
            $this->db_config['DBLocation'], 
            $this->db_config['DBName'], 
            $this->db_config['DBPassword'], 
            $this->db_config['DBUsername']
    );

    if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this code inside a class?

Comment: `$this->open_connection(db_config);` `db_config` has no `$` sign.

Comment: `open_connection()` has no argument in it's signature.

Comment: @AlexHowansky class MySQLDatabase

Answer (score 3):

`$db_config` is a variable that exists only in the method it's defined in. `$this->db_config` is a totally different variable that can be referenced by any method in the class.

In your constructor, set `$this->db_config` instead of `$db_config`:

```
$this->db_config = json_decode(...);
```

Then just call the open method without any arguments:

```
$this->open_connection();
```

Since the open method references the `$this->dbconfig` that's defined at the class level, you don't need to pass it as a parameter.

Comment: thank you so much ,i've been struggling with this for 5 hours ;_;

Comment: can I just ask is there any way i could activate a class inside a function? I need to start a query that creates 2 tables inside my function using object oriented php ,but i have no idea how.. i created class DatabaseQuery, put the queries inside there but it wont activate after i start my function..

Answer (score 1):

Proper code with comments:

```
class MySQLDatabase {
    // define class property
    protected $db_config;

    function __construct(){
        if(file_exists(ROOT_PATH.'config.php')){
            // set property value as a result of `json_decode`
            $this->db_config = json_decode(file_get_contents(ROOT_PATH.'config.php'), true);
            // json_decode can fail to return correct json
            // if your file is empty or has some bad contents
            // so we check if we really have a proper array
            if (is_array($this->db_config)) {
                // no need to pass argument to a function
                // as `db_config` property is already set
                $this->open_connection();
            }
        }
    }

    function open_connection() {
        $this->connection = mysqli_connect(
            $this->db_config['DBLocation'], 
            $this->db_config['DBName'], 
            $this->db_config['DBPassword'], 
            $this->db_config['DBUsername']
        );

        if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo "Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
    }
```